# bind mount: file content not reflected

Tags: linux, mount

I'm bind mounting a single file like this:

`mount --bind a b`

Afterwards, I can see the content of `a` if I read `b`. However, if I now make a change to `a`, that change is not reflected with `b`, which is unexpected.

Did I misunderstand what bind mount does?

Comment: How did you modify the file? Maybe the editor created a new file and replaced it, so the bind mount points to the (now deleted) old one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you bind-mount to a file it links to the actual inode of a file (just like a hard link). So if you use an editor which produces a new file you will not see the changes.

When you modify the file in-place (like `echo text >> alias`) it will see the changes.

Just as an reminder, you can see the inode number if a file with `ls -li`.

Some editors allow to turn off swapping in new temporary files. This is a bit more risky but preserves the file identity. (I think in *vim* you need the `backupcopy=yes` option.)

And in case you wonder what a good alternative is, a symbolic link points to the aliased file by name or to bind-mount a whole directory.

Comment: thanks for the info! it's great